# snmpget returns "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID"

Tags: net-snmp, snmpd

I am trying to configure SNMP agent as per the below link.

http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/toolkit/mib_module/

1. I have placed .c and .h file in the agent/mibgroup folder then `./configure --with-mib-modules="nstAgentModuleObject"`
2. make
3. make install
4. run snmpd

Now i am not able to fetch variable value with the following command

```
snmpget localhost NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0
```

It gives below error for me.

```
root@Naseeb:/home/admin-pc/Naseeb/Projects/EMS/net-snmp-5.4.4# snmpget -v2c -c public localhost NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0
NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentModuleObject.0 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

Please let me know is there anything missing in the steps.

Answer (score -1):

The steps you followed seems to be correct. To confirm if the nstAgentModuleObject is correctly registered, start the snmpd with logs using the following command:
snmpd -f -Lo0-6d -DnstAgentModuleObject

Also make sure you place the MIB file in the correct directory (from where the snmpd searches for MIB)