# snmpget: No such object available on this agent at this OID

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am trying to add my own MIB-Module into a snmp agent, following this tutorial: http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_MIB_Module
Now, I followed the tutorial step by step and doubled checked everything, searched a really long time but nothing helped me fixing my problem!

I am using net-snmp version 5.7.3

I implemented the following code into the net-snmp/agent/mibgroup directory:

```
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>
#include <net-snmp/agent/net-snmp-agent-includes.h>
#include "nstAgentModuleObject.h"

/*
* the variable we want to tie an OID to.  The agent will handle all
** GET and SET requests to this variable changing it's value as needed.
*/

static long nstAgentModuleObject = 42;

/*
* our initialization routine, automatically called by the agent 
* (to get called, the function name must match init_FILENAME()) 
*/
void
init_nstAgentModuleObject(void)
{
static oid      nstAgentModuleObject_oid[] =
    { 1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 8072, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 0 };

/*
 * a debugging statement.  Run the agent with -DnstAgentModuleObject to see
 * the output of this debugging statement. 
 */
DEBUGMSGTL(("nstAgentModuleObject",
            "Initializing the nstAgentModuleObject module\n"));


/*
 * the line below registers our variables defined above as
 * accessible and makes it writable.  A read only version of any
 * of these registration would merely call
 * register_read_only_int_instance() instead.  The functions
 * called below should be consistent with your MIB, however.
 */

DEBUGMSGTL(("nstAgentModuleObject",
            "Initalizing nstAgentModuleObject scalar integer.  Default value = %d\n",
            nstAgentModuleObject));

netsnmp_register_long_instance("nstAgentModuleObject",
                              nstAgentModuleObject_oid,
                              OID_LENGTH(nstAgentModuleObject_oid),
                              &nstAgentModuleObject, NULL);

DEBUGMSGTL(("nstAgentModuleObject",
            "Done initalizing nstAgentModuleObject module\n"));
}
```

I ran ./configure --with-mib-modules="nstAgentModuleObject", followed by make and make install. So the nstAgentModuleObject should be integrated in the snmpd agent.

The associated MIB NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB is saved in /usr/local/snmp/mbis, as well as /~/.snmp/mibs.

I added mibs +ALL in the snmpd.conf to make sure the MIB is loaded correctly. Also I used export MIBS=+all, just in case another .conf is read which should not be the case.

Using following commands I get the results shown below:

```
snmptranslate -Of NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB:nstAgentModuleObject
.iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.netSnmp.netSnmpExamples.netSnmpTutorialMIB.nstMIBObjects.nstAgentModulesObject

snmptranslate -On NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB:nstAgentModuleObject
.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.4.1.1.1
```

Now, running snmpget with the specified OID gives me this error(appending a 0 on the end since its a scalar. Results in the same error without it as well).

```
snmpget -v2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.4.1.1.1.0
NET-SNMPEXAMPLES-MIB::netSnmpExamples.4.1.1.1.0 = No Such Object availaible on this agent at this OID
```

It seems like the MIB-module is not properly build-in to the agent, but I can't think of a reason why.

I know the same question has been posted before here, but it didn't receive any answer.(**[snmpget returns "No Such Object available on this agent at this OID"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974249/snmpget-returns-no-such-object-available-on-this-agent-at-this-oid?s=1|1.5045)**)
So I want to try my luck and hope someone can help me out!

Comment: Is agent responing at all ? e.g. to 'snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost' or to 'snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost  1.3.6.1.4.1.8072'

Comment: Yes it is. Using snmpget -v2c -c public localhost sysUpTime.0 gives me a valid respone for example. I am not at work right now, so I cant test it, but looking at the last snmpget I gave in my post shows that he can find all the MIBs in the agnet up until netSnmpExamples, which should be .8072?

Comment: Using a different pc with an older debian version right now, and suddenly it works without doing anything different as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue,
It didn't work with 5.6.2.

How I solved it:

I've upgraded to 5.7.3 , then it started working.
you need to take care for the following:

1. configure the package (on build) to support agentx) with --with-mib-modules=agentx
   this is my configure:

   ```
     ./configure --prefix=/usr --build=i386-linux --host=arm-linux --target=arm-linux --with-ar=arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-ar --with-cc=arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc --with-ld=arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-ld --with-cflags="-O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp" --with-endianness=big --with-ldflags=-Bstatic --enable-mini-agent --with-mib-modules="mibII ip-mib if-mib tcp-mib udp-mib ucd_snmp target agent_mibs notification-log-mib snmpv3mibs notification agentx" --without-openssl --without-perl-modules --disable-embedded-perl --disable-shared --with-default-snmp-version="2" --with-sys-contact="root" --with-sys-location="unknown" --with-logfile="/var/log/snmpd.log" --with-persistent-directory="/var/net-snmp" --disable-manuals
   ```
2. add agentx to snmpd.conf
   This is my snmpd.config

   ```
   master  agentx

   rocommunity public rwcommunity private

   com2sec readonly  default         public 
   com2sec readwrite default     private
   ```
3. started snmpd with debug, to give more details:

   ```
   snmpd -f -Lo: -Dagentx
   ```
4. Then start the agentx application

The following tutorial also helped:

http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_Subagent

Comment: How does one 'start the agentx application', and what does that do?  I have never seen that instructed before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to include the trailing `0` when you create your OID array. I use `netsnmp_create_handler_registration` in my code base instead of `netsnmp_register_long_instance`, but this is what I generally do.

```cpp
static oid nstAgentModuleObject_oid[] = { 1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 8072, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using code and MIB from this repository: https://github.com/net-snmp/subagent-example

Copy the nstAgentSubagentObject.c, nstAgentSubagentObject.h into

```
net-snmp/agent/mibgroup/
```

Copy the NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB.txt into the `net-snmp/mibs/`

```
./configure --with-mib-modules="nstAgentSubagentObject"
make, sudo make install
```

To run the snmpd agent:

```
sudo snmpd -f -V -L -d -c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

snmpget -v 2c 192.168.1.105 -c public NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentSubagentObject.0
```

**Output**: NET-SNMP-TUTORIAL-MIB::nstAgentSubagentObject.0 = INTEGER: 2

According to this tutorial:http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_Subagent

Here its mentioned in the "**Beginner Tips**" section that certain changes need to be done to the "**Access Control**" section. I followed those comments and I was able to run **snmpget**.

Also you could share your snmpd.conf file its contents.